# Can tar split and write and read volume files from FAT32 media?

Tags: tar

*VtR reviewers: Using external tools is not a "tar" command, so, this is not a duplicate of those other mentioned questions.*

FAT32 supports max 4gb files. To use my 16GB media, I've been battling with tar's -L and -M and -F and -V switches, and managed (with a hackery -F kludge) to get tar to split my archive into multiple smaller files - all good.

However - I can't work out how to get it to read those back in...

Can someone tell me what tar command I need to type to store 10gigs of files into a FAT32 USB drive using tar, and what tar command is later needed to read them back out again?

Comment: Thanks heaps!  Bottom line - looks like others hit the same problem I did (no way to recombine tar archives, and no way to properly name the last filename in the set [-F does not get called at the end]) - so it appears as if the actual correct answer is "there is no way to do this"  (external tools like split and cat need to be used).  Pity.  Wasn't ideal anyhow (didn't handle compression)...